# Why can't I use max with Python to find maximum one-digit integer in array?

Tags: python, max

I had an interview recently and was asked to solve the following problem using Python:

Write a function:

```
def solution(A):
```

such that, given an array `A` consisting of N integers, it returns the maximum among all one-digit integers.

For example, given array A as follows:

```
[-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473]
```

the function should return 1.

Assume that:

- N is an integer within the range [1...1,000]
- Each element of array `A` is an integer within the range [-10,000..10,000].
- There is at least one element in array `A` which satisfies the condition in the task statement.

I came up with the following solution which I thought was elegant, but the score I got was only 55%:

```
def solution(A):
    return max([i for i in A if len(str(i))==1])
```

Why is this solution incorrect?

Comment: `-6` is one digit. But `len(str(-6))` is `2`?

Comment: Does the interviewer consider `-2` to be a one-digit number? Your script only considers positive one-digit numbers. Admittedly, I'd argue that the question is ambiguous on that point and should be worded differently so as to clarify, but that may account for the difference.

Comment: Also, any interview question that tells you to call a Python local variable *capital A* was definitely written by someone who doesn't actually use Python.

Comment: Also converting an integer to a string is not that elegant. You could have used `if -9 <= i <= 9`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo excuse me,why "local variable capital A" was who  doesn't actually use Python?

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer Not the original commenter, but in my view not only is this terrible style (non-descriptive in nature) but variables beginning with a capital letter are stylistically reserved for class names.

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer - per pep8, local variables should be `lower_case_with_underscores` and they should be descriptive. `A` isn't either.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I wasn't covering negative one-digit integers with my solution. `max([i for i in A if -9 <= i <= 9])` seems to cover all the cases. @Selcuk If you post your solution, I will accept it.

Comment: @esqew ,@tdelaney Got it , very thanks !

Comment: I believe [@NielGodfreyPonciano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201441/2011147) is smarter given the restrictions in this particular question.

Comment: @Selcuk which restriction is not going to be met if I do `max(i for i in a if i < 10)`?

Comment: @sprogissd There is nothing with that one, it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that ticks more points in my book.

```
def solution(integers):
    """Return max single digit integer in sequence `integers`"""
    try:
        return max(i for i in integers if -9 <= i <= 9)
    except ValueError:
        return ValueError("Could not find single digit integer in list")

print(solution([-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473]))
```

It uses a descriptive parameter name, has a comment, does a simple comparison for digit size and uses a generator with the built in function `max` instead of the needless list. It also reraises the most expected fault with a more topical error message. This function is easier to maintain and use.

Comment: This is the logic I went this, although as Selcuk has pointed out, `max(i for i in a if i < 10)` is a cleaner approach.

Comment: That doesn't work for large negative numbers. Did you mean `abs(i)`? That was my original solution but I changed to the comparison under the shakey assumption that the comparison is faster.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for large negative numbers? Please provide an example of an array it wouldn't work with?

Comment: @sprogissd `[-11, 33]` would report `-11` as a 1 digit number.

Answer (score 4):

Not the most elegant. This assumes that e.g. -3 is single digit.

This algorithm will play by the rules set. Considering the constraints:

- The number is **-10,000** to 10,000
- There is **at least one element** which satisfies the condition

Then we can just guard all numbers beyond 9 to be the lowest -10,001 so that they are not considered to be max. We don't need to care for numbers lower than -9 as we are sure there is at least 1 element (that is a single digit whether positive or negative, either way greater than those numbers lower than -9) that will satisfy the condition.

```
print(
    max(
        [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473, 5, 4, 67, 7, 3, 56],
        key=lambda num: -10001 if num > 9 else num
    )
)
print(
    max(
        [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 10, -5, -8, 67],
        key=lambda num: -10001 if num > 9 else num
    )
)
```

Output:

```
7
-5
```

Comment: Good thinking. You could also simply use `max(i for i in a if i < 10)`.

Comment: I haven't thought of that! Yes indeed, that is the better (if not best) version that plays by  the rules :)